# How to detect a Yo-Yo has hit the end of its string?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, string

I made a yo-yo machine a couple years ago and I'd like to automate it so it yo-yos on its own:

http://vimeo.com/20126959

Currently the machine is hand-cranked. I have to manually observe when the yo-yo is at the end of its string and crank the cam to make an elastic band retract the yo-yo back up.

I was thinking of using a motor and sensor. Having the sensor trigger the motor when it knows the yo-yo is low enough.

Really though, I'd like to see if anyone has a more **elegant solution that works on a physical/mechanical principle.**

Maybe I could take advantage of a mechanism similar to a *bird-drinking water desk decoration* and attach a yo-yo to it?

I'm sure this will seem stupid to some people, so sorry in advance if this post frustrated you.

Answer (score 0):

If somehow you were able to attach a force sensor like a scale, the YoYo will pull down at its full weight only when hitting the end of the string. So if you were to look hypothetically at the weight of the end of the YoYo, and see when this scale hits that weight, that's when you know it's hit the end.